# Simply want to repair a disk

Tags: ps3

folks:

I've been going about this all wrong. I have a corrupted drive froma PS3 (two, in fact), and no Windows box on which to run a disk utility. (I'm a Mac girl.) I thought I'd be clever and install Ubuntu long enough to run the disk repair utility under that to attempt to repair my drives, but I can't work with the .iso file: I'm getting the messages "medium-write error" (with a DVD) or "Invalid argument" (with a USB stick). Multiple downloads of the .iso don't change a thing.

It's time to punt. This was a dumb idea, trying to get a full-blown OS when all I wanna accomplish is one tiny thing (repair a disc drive). Let's go at this from a different angle: where can I find a small, compact, unfussy *nix I can easily install on my Mac just long enough to attempt these repairs? I realize you folks eat, sleep, and breathe Ubuntu, but I'm hoping you'll take pity on a broke, disabled vet and steer me toward the solution I need, bearing in mind I haven't access to Windows, and I can't go buying stuff. I oughtta be able to get this done: it ought not be so frustratingly, tear-inducingly hard. Or is it possible I can use the Terminal on my Mac with the commands I was given here the other day (dosfsck)? If that'd do it, then I'll be as happy as a pig in mud. No more funking around trying to extract balky .iso files.

I'd be ever so grateful for advice. My PS3s and PS4 are the most important things in my life.

Binky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://apple.stackexchange.com is a very nice place to find out how to make the command line dance in OS X.

As for a lightweight Linux to solve your problem, I'd recommend  [Lubuntu 14.10](http://lubuntu.net)  which [fits on a CD](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.10/release/lubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386.iso), and will work on Intel Macs, while giving you a full feature set.

And, please select the answer here which serves you best and click on the checkmark at left, to give attaboys/attagirls to the best answer, so other folks can see what works, and so the folks who donate their time to delve into answers get ten points closer to Immunity to Kryptonite or Eternal Enlightenment.

Comment: I've put a check mark next to one answer which was very helpful. (Alas, I wasn't able to install Ubuntu, but I found the answer useful if I _had_ been able to install it!) (The answer to my other question didn't end up being useful.) I suspect this answer is going to be useful, though (the part about alubuntu), and I'll find out tomorrow, so I'll be back, ideally to leave you a check mark! Thanks very much; I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: Aha! I see what Apple.stackexchange.com is. These stackexchange places are VERY cool (I read a buttload of info about Borderlands the other night when I discovered this Ubuntu place) and wish that I'd discovered StackExchange a loooong time ago. You get your check mark _now_. Now' é earned it!

Comment: I mean the video game. I've platinum edition the first two already and found soooo many tips that woulda improved both games immensely had I known them (sob!), but now I have some ammo for the Pre-Sequel! Assuming I'm able to resurrect my hard drive, I'm gonna use the hell out of those tips!